# how to refer values of one jsp file to other jsp

Tags: jsp-tags

I am calling jsp on `<a href>` tag like this

```
<div align="left"><a href="jsp/admin/UpdateProject.jsp"><%=searchList1.getProjid()%></a></div>
```

I want to get the value of `searchlist1.getProjid` in `UpdateProject.jsp`

How can I do it... please suggest me with example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it as parameter:

```
<div align="left"><a href="jsp/admin/UpdateProject.jsp?projid=<%=searchList1.getProjid()%>"><%=searchList1.getProjid()%></a></div>
```

And then use it in the new jsp like:

```
request.getParameter('projid');
```